# New Google Sites Announcements and Recent Post Methods

Tags: google-chrome, google-sites, google-sites-2016

I am currently working on a project that involves upgrading an intranet running Classic Google Sites to new Google Sites. It appears that when upgrading we will lose the announcements and recent post functionality if we upgrade. I am having difficulty locating an example of this functionality being used within new Google Sites on the web. How are developers working around this issue in new Google Sites? Are they working around this issue?

Specific problems:

- New Google Sites does not support the gadgets that classic Sites used, so these will be lost.
- This includes content you added via an iframe because the iframe was a gadget.
- You can add content in iframes and make your own gadgets

As per the last list item, can anyone chime in on a preferred gadget for this purpose or point to gadget development source examples that achieves the old announcements functionality seen in classic sites?

Edit: Looking at this deeper, it appears we can achieve similar functionality by adding announcements as a blog post or some other block content. It looks like we can embed HTML. However, linked content need to come from a secure url. I suppose what we are looking for were people to weigh in on their experience using these sort of workarounds.